# apache error log: Invalid method in request \xf1-\xda\xd1\xeaG'$\xff\xc2B\\\xa9\x9a\xf3\x8a\xcbIE\xa0\xfa\x95\xcf\x86

Tags: apache-2.2

Today I got this when browsing error log of my apache production server.

```
 Invalid method in request \xf1-\xda\xd1\xeaG'$\xff\xc2B\\\xa9\x9a\xf3\x8a\xcbIE\xa0\xfa\x95\xcf\x86
```

what does it means?

Comment: Maybe somebody is looking for a security vulnerability. Another possibility is that due to a configuration mistake client and server are not using the same protocol. For example it might be that the client is talking https and the server expect http.

Comment: Maybe HeartBleed? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @kasperd said, this looks like a client was talking SSL and Apache expected HTTP traffic. This might be because someone actually tried that (https://your.domain:80/ for example), or then it could be a (temporary) misconfiguration in your load-balancer / firewall / whatever.

Doesn't look too scary.

Comment: Is there a way to translate \xf1-\xda\xd1\xeaG'$\xff\xc2B\\\xa9\x9a\xf3\x8a\xcbIE\xa0\xfa\x95\xcf\x86 to something human-readable?